# Macro Only Finishes If Run Though VBA Application or Macro List

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 3 master sheets that I frequently want open (May, June, and July). I have multiple other macros that grab data from these master sheets.

I've created a macro (**OpenFiles**) that opens them. I want to be able to call **OpenFiles** at the start of a macro if I know I will be referencing one of these master sheets.

Sub **OpenFiles** calls another sub(*zzGetIt*) that checks if the workbook is already open, otherwise it opens it. It works perfectly if I run it from the VBA application, or by choosing it in the macro list in Excel. But **if I use a hotkey to call it, or if it is called through another macro, it exits out of all subs after opening a single file** (and ends on that workbook instead of activating my original active workbook).

It will open a workbook if one of them is missing, but it will never open more than one (if, say I have only 1/3 workbooks open- 2 should open). And the only scenario where the macro will *continue* to the msgbox at the end is if all three files are already open.

Please help- I think this must be super obvious since the macro runs fine if I run it from VBA.

I've tried the following:

- Removed any error handling that could be hiding a problem with the
  sub/function
- Set Tools>Options>"Break on all Errors" and I still don't receive any
  errors when the sub ends early.
- Went through the whole sub with F8- it runs perfectly when I use that.
- Call **OpenFiles** multiple times in a macro but the sub ends after the sub is called the first time so the rest never even run.

```
    Sub zzGetIt(sfullname As String)

    Dim ZGetIt As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Dim ReadOnly As Boolean    
    Dim o As Boolean

    Dim sFile As String

    sFile = Dir(sfullname)

        MsgBox ("Trying to fetch")
        For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name = sFile Then
            o = True
            Exit For
        End If
        Next wb

        If o = False Then
        Set zGetIt = Workbooks.Open(sfullname, ReadOnly:=ReadOnly)
        End If
        'reset o
        o = False
        MsgBox ("Finished fetching " & sFile)
    End Sub
```

```
    Sub OpenFiles()

    Dim Current As Worksheet
    Set Current = ActiveSheet

    Dim May As String
    Dim Jun As String
    Dim Jul As String

    May = "A:\Files\My Stuff\05 May 2019 - Master.xlsx"
    Jun = "A:\Files\My Stuff\06 June 2019 - Master.xlsx"
    Jul = "A:\Files\My Stuff\07 July 2019 - Master.xlsx"

    Call zzGetIt(May)
    Call zzGetIt(Jun)
    Call zzGetIt(Jul)

    Current.Activate
    Set Current = Nothing

    Msgbox("I can only get this msgbox if I run from macro list or 
    VBA application OR if all 3 workbooks were already open before I ran the 
    macro")

    End Sub
```

If May needs to be opened it will stop at May so I do not receive the msgbox after the sub is called for the first time.

I want the macro to open any of the three workbooks that are not already open and I need it to continue until the msgbox at the very end pops up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue... found [this article](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/93048-vba-open-workbook-macro-hangs). The issue is using a hotkey with SHIFT. Hotkey used must be lower-case or use a button to call the macro

```
Ctrl+Shift+a
'won't work

Ctrl+a
'will work
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code that might cause the observed behavior. But I would still do it differently. Perhaps this will help. I've revised your procedures that check for the file already open/open the file if not already open, but apart from that the main difference is that I'm calling this procedure in a loop from `OpenFiles`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub OpenFiles()

Dim Current As Worksheet
Set Current = ActiveSheet
Dim files As New Collection
Dim file

files.Add "A:\Files\My Stuff\05 May 2019 - Master.xlsx"
files.Add "A:\Files\My Stuff\06 June 2019 - Master.xlsx"
files.Add "A:\Files\My Stuff\07 July 2019 - Master.xlsx"

For Each file In files
    Debug.Print "Fetching file " & file
    If isFileOpen(CStr(file)) Then
        Debug.Print file & " is already open :) "
    Else
        Call GetFile(CStr(file), False)
    End If
Next

Current.Activate
Set Current = Nothing

MsgBox ("Finished!")

End Sub
Private Function isFileOpen(fullPath$) As Boolean
Dim wb As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks(Dir(fullPath))
If Err.Number = 0 Then isFileOpen = True
End Function

Private Sub GetFile(fullPath$, readOnly As Boolean)
' No error handling here, this SHOULD raise an error if the file can't 
' be opened for any reason (invalid path, locked/in-use unless readOnly=True, etc. 
Debug.Print "Attempting to open " & fullPath
Workbooks.Open fullPath, readOnly:=readOnly

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @David Zemens, thanks so much for your help. I've never used collections before... thats a neat tool. Unfortunately with my limited knowledge and reading as much as I can, still can't figure out what is missing in your code. Can you please edit your answer to fix the error I'm getting **ByRef Argument type mismatch** on line `If isFileOpen(file) then`. Something about the way you've referenced `file` is wrong...

Comment: sorry, do `If isFileOpen(CString(file)) Then`

Comment: you'll also need to wrap it here: `Call GetFile(CStr(file), False)`

Comment: And one more revision in the `GetFile` function, all revisions I have made in the answer now.

Comment: The `ByRef` problem is that the functions are expecting *string* type, but by necessity a collection can only iterate over Object or Variant type. Here, `file` is variant, so we need to cast it to string using the `CStr` conversion function (built-in).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of what you're fixing... one more error- `Subscript out of range` for `Set wb = Workbooks(dir(fullpath))`. I really am trying to debug this myself, I promise! Lots of stuff here I've not come across before.

Comment: That error is expected if the file is *not* already open, and it *should* be swallowed by the preceding `On Error Resume Next`. if it's not, check your debug settings. The only way that error should raise, in this context, is if you have set to break on all errors.

Comment: Yep, good catch. Turned that back off and it runs fine. This one also stops each time it opens a file :(. Same issue I had with my old macro...

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that one or more of those workbooks contains some code in one of its event handlers (`Workbook_Open`, etc.) that is somehow interrupting or causing this failure. If you put a breakpoint on the `For Each file` line, and run the code from `Call` statement in another procedure, can you then step through in debug mode maybe and see what else might be happening when these files are opened/activated?

Comment: I don't use any event handling at all. I don't understand what changed but now it is only opening one file no matter how I run the macro. It gets to sub **GetFile** and exits after opening the workbook. It doesn't go back to the loop. I've tried having it open three blank files with new names in case it was my master sheets messing with it... same problem.

Comment: Does the procedure actually *stop* (ends runtime) or does it just hang indefinitely

Comment: I didn't change anything but now its back to only opening a single book if called from another maco or a hotkey. Works perfectly when run through VBA application including F8. I've tried seeing if it has anything to do with what workbook(s) it has to open but it really doesn't seem to be affected by anything like that.

Comment: That doesn't help explain anything nor does it answer my questions about debugging. I'm sorry but I can't reproduce the problem and if you can't or won't debug this, I can't offer any more assistance.

Comment: Kind of hard to debug when it runs perfectly when I'm watching it. I've solved the issue... found [this article](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/93048-vba-open-workbook-macro-hangs) the issue is using a hotkey with SHIFT. Hotkey used must be lower-case or use a button to call the macro. Appreciate your help trying to fix this, David